# Path is not match any of these

Tags: django

I always get this error **"The empty path didn't match any of these."** When I try to access the page through this url:

```
url('^about/$',views.AboutView.as_view(),name = 'about')
```

and when I remove `"^about/$"` part, then it works:

```
url('',views.AboutView.as_view(),name = 'about')
```

How could I resolve it?

This is link for call:

```
<li><a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'about'%}">About</a></li>
```

this is view.py

```
class AboutView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'about.html'
```

and, this urlpatterns

```
    urlpatterns = [
    url('^about/$',views.AboutView.as_view(),name = 'about')
]
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. The empty path does indeed not match "about/". What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Do you have, by any chance, another view with the name `about`?

Comment: when I try to call the page via "^about/$" it always shows error "The empty path didn't match any of these." and when I remove "^about/$" then it works.

Comment: please post your all url files

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, No, I don't have any about view.

Comment: @AliRazaJaveed: it is not about the view, it is about the urls.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: that is the mean I want to say, it is my url file `from django.conf.urls import url
from blog import views


urlpatterns = [
    url('^about/$',views.AboutView.as_view(),name = 'about')
]
`

Comment: @user6837382:  first is `from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('blog.urls'))
]` and, second one is `from django.conf.urls import url
from blog import views


urlpatterns = [
    url('about',views.AboutView.as_view(),name='about')
]`

Comment: why you are following different methods on both url files. On main url you use the path method and in your app url you use the old method, so use the same as the main url.

Comment: What is the url you're typing in your browser ? If you're just trying to access the site's root url (ie "http://localhost:8000/"), then OF COURSE there's no matching urlpattern. You have to go to "http://localhost:8000/about/" to go to the `about` view.

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.conf.urls import url 
from blog import views 

urlpatterns = [ url('about',views.AboutView.as_view(),name='about') ]
```

instead of this

```
from django.urls import path
from blog import views 
urlpatterns = [
    path('about/', views.AboutView.as_view(),name='about'),
```

use this pattern same as your main url

Answer (score 0):

path('about/', views.AboutView, name='about'),

Comment: still getting the same error "about/ [name='about']
The empty path didn't match any of these."

Comment: try to add appname in the template: <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'appname:about'%}">About</a></li>

Comment: path is belongs to `django >= 2.0`. If you uses a pattern you can use... ```re_path(r'^about/$', AboutView.as_view())```

Comment: I did it too, but still the same `<li><a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'blog:about'%}">About</a></li>` and `from django.conf.urls import url
from blog import views

app_name = 'blog'
urlpatterns = [
    url('about',views.AboutView.as_view(),name='about')
]
`

Comment: What's your django version?

Comment: @GovindaMalavipathirana: 2.21

Answer (score 0):

It's not good to follow 2 ways of creating urls, Since `django==2.0` they have introduced very nice and easy way to declare urls.
In the old way...

```
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^about/$', AboutView.as_view(), name="about")
]
```

But In the new way it's lot more cleaner...

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('about/', view.AboutView.as_view())
]
```

But if you want to stick with the regular expressions, Use `re_path()` instead of `path()`.

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'about/$', view.AboutView.as_view())
]
```

In my it's better stay with one pattern, old or new but not both. It makes your code look more cleaner.